# Debian: GPG cannot fetch Linux Kernel key

Tags: linux, kernel, gpg, signature

I am in the process of recompiling the kernel on Debian.  Following [the instructions on kernel.org](https://www.kernel.org/category/signatures.html), the first step is to verify the signature.  But GPG complains that it cannot find the public key:

```
# gpg --verify linux-3.12.22.tar.sign 
gpg: Signature made Wed 11 Jun 2014 17:22:35 CEST using RSA key ID 6092693E
gpg: Can't check signature: public key not found
```

I have tried to fetch the key:

```
# gpg --recv-keys 6092693E
gpg: no keyserver known (use option --keyserver)
gpg: keyserver receive failed: bad URI
```

I have tried to set the keyserver:

```
# gpg --keyserver subkeys.pgp.net --recv-keys 6092693E
gpg: requesting key 6092693E from hkp server subkeys.pgp.net
gpg: keyserver timed out
gpg: keyserver receive failed: keyserver error
```

What is the problem?  Thanks.

Software:

- Debian GNU/Linux 6
- GPG 1.4.10

**EDIT:** I do have a firewall, but its rules don't block outbound traffic.  However, connecting to the keyserver on a different port:

```
$ gpg --keyserver subkeys.pgp.net:80 --recv-keys 6092693E
gpg: requesting key 6092693E from subkeys.pgp.net:80
gpgkeys: no keyserver host provided
gpg: keyserver internal error
gpg: keyserver receive failed: keyserver error
```

Answer (score 3):

As error message, you haven't configured gpg server.

Try this:

```
gpg --keyserver subkeys.pgp.net --recv-keys 6092693E && gpg --export --armor 6092693E \
| sudo apt-key add -
```

**Updated**

It seems that you can not connect to server:

```
gpg: keyserver timed out
```

Do you have a firewall block port 11371 of hkp service.

You can use port 80 instead of 17371:

```
gpg --keyserver subkeys.pgp.net:80 --recv-keys 6092693E
```

Comment: Thanks, but I would rather not run a command that I don't understand.  How is supposed the second call to *gpg* to run if the first command in the chain fails?  *gpg --export --armor 6092693E* alone does print a key that can be passed to *apt-key add* but how does *gpg* get it, while *--recv-keys* fails to fetch it?

Comment: @Elena: updated my answer.