# Unable to verify the kernel signature "gpg: Can't check signature: public key not found"

Tags: gpg

In order to compile a new kernel on my Debian jessie, I am trying to verify the GPG key , following the instruction on the official [website](https://www.kernel.org/category/signatures.html).

I have download the the `linux-3.18.35.tar.sign` and `linux-3.18.35.tar.xz` version and unzip it using `unzx`.

To verify the `.tar` archive using the command :

```
gpg --verify linux-3.18.35.tar.sign
```

I get:

```
gpg: assuming signed data in `linux-3.18.35.tar'
gpg: Signature made Wed 08 Jun 2016 01:19:29 AM CET using RSA key ID 6092693E
gpg: Can't check signature: public key not found
```

To get the public key from the PGP keyserver  :

```
#gpg --keyserver hkp://keys.gnupg.net --recv-keys 6092693E

gpg: requesting key 6092693E from hkp server keys.gnupg.net
?: keys.gnupg.net: Host not found
gpgkeys: HTTP fetch error 7: couldn't connect: Connection refused
gpg: no valid OpenPGP data found.
gpg: Total number processed: 0
```

I get a similar problem with the `4.4.13` version too.

I have tried the following [answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/138523/153195),

```
# gpg --keyserver subkeys.pgp.net --recv-keys 6092693E && gpg --export --armor 6092693E | sudo apt-key add -

gpg: requesting key 6092693E from hkp server subkeys.pgp.net
gpg: keyserver timed out
gpg: keyserver receive failed: keyserver error
```

And:

```
# gpg --keyserver subkeys.pgp.net:80 --recv-keys 6092693E

gpg: requesting key 6092693E from subkeys.pgp.net:80
gpgkeys: no keyserver host provided
gpg: keyserver internal error
gpg: keyserver receive failed: keyserver error
```

How to verify the kernel signature correctly?

Comment: Does `--keyserver hkp://subkeys.pgp.net:80` do any better?

Comment: Unfortunately doesn't help.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You only need to have the public key in your keyring:

```
gpg --keyserver subkeys.pgp.net --recv-keys 0x38DBBDC86092693E
```

([use the long identifier](http://gwolf.org/node/4070)!). If it times out, try again — there are multiple servers, and some of them seem to be having issues currently. `apt-key` etc. aren't involved in this at all.

Once you have the key in your keyring,

```
gpg --verify linux-3.18.35.tar.sign
```

should work.

You can also [configure a key server pool instead](https://help.riseup.net/en/security/message-security/openpgp/best-practices#use-the-sks-keyserver-pool-instead-of-one-specific-server-with-secure-connections) (this is a good idea anyway):

1. install `gnupg-curl` (`apt-get install gnupg-curl` on Debian);
2. download the SKS CA

   ```
   cd ~/.gnupg; wget https://sks-keyservers.net/sks-keyservers.netCA.pem
   ```
3. [verify it](https://sks-keyservers.net/verify_tls.php);
4. add the following line to your `~/.gnupg/gpg.conf`, or change it if it's already present:

   ```
   keyserver hkps://hkps.pool.sks-keyservers.net
   ```

   and set up the certificate by either adding

   ```
   keyserver-options ca-cert-file=/home/.../.gnupg/sks-keyservers.netCA.pem
   ```

   to `~/.gnupg/gpg.conf` (for GnuPG 1) or

   ```
   keyserver hkps://hkps.pool.sks-keyservers.net
   hkp-cacert /home/.../.gnupg/sks-keyservers.netCA.pem
   ```

   to `~/.gnupg/dirmngr.conf` (for GnuPG 2), replacing the `...` in the path with the appropriate value for your home directory in both cases.

Once you've done that,

```
gpg --recv-keys 0x38DBBDC86092693E
```

should retrieve the key reliably.

If all that fails, you can download and import the key manually:

```
curl 'http://pgp.surfnet.nl:11371/pks/lookup?op=get&search=0x38DBBDC86092693E' > gregkh.key
gpg --import gregkh.key
```

Comment: After runing `gpg --verify linux-3.18.35.tar.sign` i recived `gpg: Good signature from "Greg Kroah-Hartman...` And " There is no indication that the signature belongs to the owner"

Comment: @GAD3R I'm not sure why that would fix it either... The messages you're getting from `gpg` now mean that the signature is valid, but that you don't have any personal connection to Greg KH's key. If you don't have a GPG key in the strong set that's perfectly normal. What it all means is that the archive you downloaded was really signed by key 0x38DBBDC86092693E, but you don't have any means of verifying that the key actually belongs to Greg KH (through key signatures ultimately connected to your GPG key).

Comment: On a mac with gpg 2.2.23 installed via homebrew this did not work. I was able to download keys with `gpg --keyserver pool.sks-keyservers.net --recv-keys <keyid>`

Comment: SKS keyservers seem to be [deprecated](https://sks-keyservers.net), and the DNS records were deleted on 2021-06-21. Try `host hkps.pool.sks-keyservers.net` or `host pool.sks-keyservers.net`. Or `keys.gnupg.net` for that matter.

Comment: @x-yuri yes, see [sks-keyservers gone. What to use instead?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/656205/86440) I suppose I should update all my answers which refer to SKS...

Comment: @StephenKitt With all your answers, you have your work cut out for you! :) Your not alone though; there are many out-dated OpenPGP-related answers and web pages on the Internet (some even on gnupg.org). This answer could probably benefit with generaous copying from https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/352774/22812