# Downgrade XUbuntu kernel

Tags: kernel, xubuntu

I'm now running XUbuntu 16.04 with kernel 4.4.0-31 and now I need to somehow downgrade kernel to version 4.1.24. Is there any way to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Install required packages:**

```
sudo apt-get install git fakeroot build-essential 
sudo apt-get install libssl-dev bc ncurses-dev xz-utils
sudo apt-get install kernel-package
```

**Download the Linux kernel**

```
wget https://www.kernel.org/pub/linux/kernel/v4.x/linux-4.1.24.tar.xz
wget https://www.kernel.org/pub/linux/kernel/v4.x/linux-4.1.24.tar.sign
```

[**verify kernel signatures**](https://www.kernel.org/category/signatures.html)

```
unxz linux linux-4.1.24.tar.xz
gpg --verify linux-4.1.24.tar.sign
```

If you get "Bad signatures" try the following  [answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/288937/153195)

```
tar xvf linux-4.1.24.tar
cd linux-4.1.24
cp /boot/config-$(uname -r) .config
make menuconfig
```

Make sure that the **Enable loadable module support** is selected.

Save and exit

**Compile the kernel**:

```
make-kpkg clean
fakeroot make-kpkg --initrd --revision=1.0.NAS kernel_image kernel_headers -j 16
```

Type the following command to find the `.deb` files:

```
 ls  ../*.deb
```

Install the kernel files:

```
sudo dpkg -i linux-headers-4.1.24_1.0.NAS_amd64.deb
sudo dpkg -i linux-image-4.1.24_1.0.NAS_amd64.deb
```

Reboot you system.

From the advanced option of GRUB, choose to boot the new kernel.

You can find the old kernel using the following command:

```
dpkg --list | egrep -i --color 'linux-image|linux-headers'
```

To remove it :

```
sudo apt-get --purge remove linux-imagexxxxx
sudo apt-get autoremove
```

**Edit**
To solve this error `unxz : linux : no such file or directory` , install `xz-utils` :

```
sudo apt-get install xz-utils
```

Comment: Error on this command: `unxz linux linux-4.1.24.tar.xz` : `unxz : linux : no such file or directory`