# gpg to import keys from a keyserver into a file

Tags: debian, ubuntu, gpg

Following up on [How to import keys from a keyserver using gpg in debian?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/334912/how-to-import-keys-from-a-keyserver-using-gpg-in-debian), which asked for importing keys from a keyserver using gpg into our own `~/.gnupg/pubring.kbx` file,

but my question is asking how to do that but save to a `.gpg` ***file*** instead, something like the following (neither is working obviously):

`gpg --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys 91E7EE5E --dearmour -o /tmp/ppa.gpg` or
`gpg --export --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys 91E7EE5E | sudo gpg --dearmour -o /tmp/ppa.gpg`

Comment: @JaromandaX, no, not spelling errors. Give it a try and you'll know.

Comment: Well, I don't know if it is another problem with `gpg` (of not behaving as the man page says), but `--dearmour` worked for me.

Comment: Sorry, I saw what I thought was a typo, apparently it's not ... bye, and good luck