# sks-keyservers gone. What to use instead?

Tags: gpg, pgp

https://sks-keyservers.net/ ([Internet Archive snapshot](https://web.archive.org/web/20220119094712/https://www.sks-keyservers.net/)) says

> This service is deprecated. This means it is no longer maintained, and new HKPS certificates will not be issued. Service reliability should not be expected.
>
> Update 2021-06-21: Due to even more GDPR takedown requests, the DNS records for the pool will no longer be provided at all.

Which keyservers can I use for `gpg --keyserver "$keyserver1" --recv-key keyid` that I can expect not will go away anytime soon?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I chose to use

- pgp.surf.nl
- keyserver.bazon.ru
- agora.cenditel.gob.ve
- pgp.benny-baumann.de

Comment: Your question acknowledged that SKS is deprecated and all keyservers using it will eventually be unreliable... what makes you think the SKS-based keyservers you listed will remain reliable?

Comment: It would be great that people stop spread servers that aren't compliant with the EU GDPR.

Comment: Why exactly? I don't live in the EU, why should I not be able to see non-complaint (and therefore non-broken) servers?

Comment: GDPR from EU isn't broken.  But it is a bit restricted in it's application by some.
What is broken is other juridical areas where they don't care about peoples confidenciality and privacy.  Like USA.

Answer (score 30):

> Which keyservers can I use for `gpg --keyserver "$keyserver1" --recv-key keyid` that I can expect not will go away anytime soon?

The recommendation is to use `keys.openpgp.org`, however this keyserver only includes User IDs for keys whose owners have personally confirmed via email (basically eliminating large swaths of of the PGP ecosystem). It also does not include *any* 3rd party signatures on keys to mitigate the possibility of a "poisoned key" attack. As of December 2021, this is the default (if none is configured by the user) keyserver for GnuPG packaged by Debian since `gnupg2 2.2.17-1` (released in 2019).

Personally, I'd recommend a Hockeypuck-based keyserver like `keyserver.ubuntu.com`, which isn't so limited (although it does strip 3rd party signatures). GnuPG has since changed this to the default as of versions 2.2.29 and 2.3.2.

Comment: I've upvoted your answer as being nice and succinct. There's lots of good documentation about `keys.opengp.org` and Hagrid but I haven't really researched Hockeypuck yet.

Comment: `keyserver.ubuntu.com` processes [takedown requests from users](https://askubuntu.com/a/1449440/1112981), so it should not give up under GDPR pressure. Unlike `keys.openpgp.org`, it is [comitted to keep peering](https://keyserver.ubuntu.com/#about) with [other servers](https://github.com/pgpkeys-eu). Finally, [GnuPG now uses it by default.](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/352774/423679)

Answer (score 9):

Alternate public PGP key servers that support access via HKP (like SKS keyservers used to):

- [keys.openpgp.org](https://keys.openpgp.org/) (based on [hagrid](https://gitlab.com/hagrid-keyserver/hagrid))
- [keyserver.ubuntu.com](https://keyserver.ubuntu.com/) (based on [Hockeypuck](https://hockeypuck.io/))
- [keys.mailvelope.com](https://keys.mailvelope.com/) (based on [Mailvelope](https://github.com/mailvelope))

Access via other protocols that are supported by GnuPG:

- LDAP: [keyserver.pgp.com](https://keyserver.pgp.com/) (based on Broadcom PGP Universal Server)

Due to the fact that the SKS key servers were taken down due to GDPR relevant problems, we should be prepared that, on the long run, only verifying key servers remain available. Verifying key servers demand that the user verifies their email address before the PGP key is published.

*(Parts of the information collected from [PGP Key Retrieval](https://savignano.atlassian.net/l/c/aHbHTodS))*

Answer (score 8):

`keys.gnupg.net` [is also gone](https://old.reddit.com/r/GnuPG/comments/oyktpm/keysgnupgnet_down_no_longer_resolves/).

At least `keyserver.ubuntu.com` is still functional. I was able to use it from GnuPG only after adding a `hkps://` prefix and a `:443` suffix:

```
gpg2 --keyserver hkps://keyserver.ubuntu.com:443 --recv-keys XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
```

Notice that [its web front-end](https://keyserver.ubuntu.com) and many others like https://pgp.key-server.io/ don't let you search for a key by its ID if you enter it like `XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX` or `XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX`, but searching for `0xXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX` or `0xXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX` works fine. It also works on https://pgp.mit.edu/, but the lookup is very slow there, and I couldn't get it working via GnuPG.

Comment: Upvoted. I'd point out that when configuring a HKPS keyserver, you can either specify the `hkps://` schema or the `:443` port number:  either will suffice to use HKP over TLS.  An advantage of HKPS is that it provides greater privacy and if the user is behind a corporate firewall, port 11371 could be blocked while 443 is unlikely to be.

Comment: `pgp.mit.edu` [say that they do not process takedown requests](https://pgp.mit.edu/faq.html), so it is not clear how they survive the GDPR, which is the concern in the OP's question. Also, they still use the SKS server software, which is [told to be susceptible to certificate spamming attacks](https://gist.github.com/rjhansen/67ab921ffb4084c865b3618d6955275f#the-certificate-spamming-attack). Finally, they [do not list gossip peers anymore](http://pgp.mit.edu/pks/lookup?op=stats), so they do not [exchange keys with other servers](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/82297/241015).

Answer (score 7):

**SUMMARY**

**The Old**

To add a little more detail to [what not2savvy has written](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/692097/215688):

Basically, PGP Keyservers were running on SKS-Keyserver code written decades ago and unmaintained. They got hacked in June 2019 and got taken down permanently. For details, see this post by the maintainer of the GnuPG FAQ **Robert J. Hansen** [SKS Keyserver Network Under Attack](https://gist.github.com/rjhansen/67ab921ffb4084c865b3618d6955275f).

**The New**

Several new PGP Keyservers have been written since which implement the [HKP Protocol](http://ietfreport.isoc.org/idref/draft-shaw-openpgp-hkp/)

- [Hagrid](https://gitlab.com/hagrid-keyserver/hagrid)
- [Mailvelope](https://github.com/mailvelope/keyserver)
- [Hockeypuck](https://hockeypuck.io)

###### Verifying Keyservers - (Use)*

[Verifying keyservers](https://keys.openpgp.org/about) are new servers which verify the email addresses of uploaded keys, and are designed to be ***”resistant to the abuse and privacy issues that plague old SKS Keyservers”***.

---

I would suggest using verifying keyservers:

- [keys.openpgp.org](https://keys.openpgp.org)
  based on hagrid and verifying
- [keys.mailvelope.com](https://keys.mailvelope.com)
  based on Mailvelope and verifying

---

The Ubuntu keyserver below does **not** verify your keys email address but is a new maintained keyserver which may implement verification in the future.

- [keyserver.ubuntu.com](https://keyserver.ubuntu.com) based on Hockeypuck - does **not** verify your email address