# Can browse internet, but ping doesn't work

Tags: arch-linux, ping, internet, pacman

I have an old laptop with Arch Linux installed on it, which I just started up for the first time in a few years. I have NetworkManager installed on it, which can seemingly connect fine to wired and wireless internet. In both cases, while I can browse the internet fine, `ping` does not get a response:

```
$ ping www.google.com
PING www.google.com (172.217.12.228) 56 (84) bytes of data.
```

So the IP address is successfully resolved, but I never get a response. I don't believe there's anything funny with the firewall going on here, as I have several other devices connected to the same internet that can ping just fine.

In case it is relevant to diagnosing the problem, the reason I'm concerned about this is that I am unable to update my packages due to some issue with updating pacman keys:

```
$ sudo pacman -S archlinux-keyring
resolving dependencies...
looking for conflicting packages...
 
Packages (1) archlinux-keyring-20211028-1.0
 
Total Installed Size:  1.36 MiB
Net Upgrade Size:      0.13 MiB
 
:: Proceed with installation? [Y/n] Y
(1/1) checking keys in keyring                                                                [############################################################] 100%
downloading required keys...
:: Import PGP key 2C146C01A952AC0F, "Erich Eckner <arch32 at eckner dot net>"? [Y/n] y
error: key "2C146C01A952AC0F" could not be looked up remotely
error: required key missing from keyring
error: failed to commit transaction (unexpected error)
Errors occurred, no packages were upgraded.
$ sudo pacman-key --refresh-keys
gpg: refreshing 116 keys from hkp://pool.sks-keyservers.net
gpg: keyserver refresh failed: No name
==> ERROR: A specified local key could not be updated from a keyserver.
```

My guess is that this is related to the ping issue, but it could be unrelated.

Comment: Can you ping via IPv6? Can you `curl` a website?

Comment: IPv6 pinging does not work, `curl` and `get` both appear to work.

Comment: Incorrectly setup firewall?

Comment: Can you ping other hosts in your network? Your router? A command like `traceroute -n 1.1.1.1` might help find out if they are being dropped, and where.

Comment: @EduardoTrápani That's a good suggestion. I can ping other hosts on my network, like my desktop. Using `tracepath -n 1.1.1.1` shows me that it gets to the gateway (192.168.0.1), but then gets no reply past that.

Comment: do other devices successfully ping? if not, perhaps your router is blocking outgoing pings (or maybe all outgoing ICMP?)

Answer (score 1):

You may have an actual networking problem, but even if that doesn't exist or is fixed or bypassed (e.g. by getting the data on a another local system and copying it over), you won't be able to access `pool.sks-keyservers.net` because **that is an ex-keyserver**, pushing up the daisies, gone to join the choir invisible, and wouldn't voom if you put 4 million volts through it. See:
[sks-keyservers gone. What to use instead?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/656205/sks-keyservers-gone-what-to-use-instead)
https://superuser.com/questions/1660444/gpg4wins-kleopatra-not-uploading-to-servers-due-to-a-no-name-error
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67251078/gpg-keyserver-send-failed-no-keyserver-available
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66217436/gpg-keyserver-receive-failed-no-name

I can fetch 2C146C01A952AC0F from keyserver.ubuntu.com (as a signing subkey of 255A76DB9A12601A) but **that key is expired** as of 2021-12-31 (i.e. 3 weeks ago).

According to https://archlinux.org/packages/core/any/archlinux-keyring/ the current version is 20220118-1 and should be signed by [Christian Hesse](https://keyserver.ubuntu.com/pks/lookup?op=vindex&fingerprint=on&exact=on&search=0x6D42BDD116E0068F) but I am not an arch-er and can't test/verify for you.