# no public key on debian 11 unable to apt update

Tags: apt, upgrade, gpg, apt-key

I've tried all methods published in older questions, such as adding from `ubuntu.keyserver`, using `gpg`, from `hkp://pool.sks-keyservers.net:80` etc, any ideas ¿?

gpg:

```
gpg --recv-keys 0E61D3BBAAEE37FE
gpg: recepción del servidor de claves fallida: No data
```

ubuntu keyserver:

```
Executing: /tmp/apt-key-gpghome.zPtWaE6tzD/gpg.1.sh --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys 0E61D3BBAAEE37FE
gpg: recepción del servidor de claves fallida: No data
```

pool.sks-keyserver:

```
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://pool.sks-keyservers.net:80 --recv-keys 0E61D3BBAAEE37FE
Warning: apt-key is deprecated. Manage keyring files in trusted.gpg.d instead (see apt-key(8)).
Executing: /tmp/apt-key-gpghome.qLLaSgFMSM/gpg.1.sh --keyserver hkp://pool.sks-keyservers.net:80 --recv-keys 0E61D3BBAAEE37FE
gpg: recepción del servidor de claves fallida: Server indicated a failure
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [sks-keyservers gone. What to use instead?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/656205/sks-keyservers-gone-what-to-use-instead)

Comment: Still facing the same error with gpg, no data, all the servers seems down. Also tried with the front-end service of the servers submitting manually the key but it drops 503 error.

Comment: Reviewers: this isn’t about using the SKS servers or not, the first two commands run don’t involve SKS and were able to connect to a keyserver. The issue is that the key doesn’t exist on the keyservers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your default server, and the Ubuntu keyserver, aren’t down; they just don’t have the key you’re asking for. 0E61D3BBAAEE37FE isn’t available from any keyserver I’m aware of.

Comment: That's the anwer, I solved my problem removing the repository that was giving me problems and then re-adding them to my list.